# How can I programmatically connect to a VPN?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7, vpn

I have a VPN connection that I keep losing, that I need to connect to our DB server, but every second or third connection fails because I have lost the VPN connection. I'd like to add somde code - for DEBUG config only - to check the VPN connection and reconnect if necessary, before proceeding to attempt the database connection.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question but I wanted to offer another idea.  If you are getting disconnected due to inactivity then open a CMD.exe window and run "ping -t <servername>" and just leave that window open which you develop.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) to check if the connection is up - then rasdial to reconnect the vpn if the connection is lost.

eg

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "VPNName Username Password");
```

You can also disconnect the VPN using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "VPNName /d");
```

**Update**

Calling rasdial with no arguments returns a list of open connections - might be a more robust solution for you.

Comment: Great stuff for rasdial, but now what do I ping to see if the network is up? I can ping any server on the VPN, but if that server is down, it will appear to my AutoVpn code that I have lost the VPN connection.

Comment: I think that will do @Paul, as that is the server I keep missing. Thanks.