# c# connect to vpn. rasdial.exe seems unreliable

Tags: c#, vpn

I can connect to vpn manually just fine each time.

I am trying to use c# to connect to a vpn.
I found this on SO,
[How can I programmatically connect to a VPN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076711/how-can-i-programmatically-connect-to-a-vpn#comment8486414_7079288)
Which shows to connect using this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rasdial.exe", "VPNName Username Password");
```

But this only seems to sometimes work. It either connects in about half a second and spends the next couple minutes going back and forth between Connecting to __.... and Verifying username and password... until it gives a remote access error 800.

This never happens when trying to connect normally with windows.

Any idea what might cause this issue and how to resolve it?

Comment: This isn't a C# or programming related problem. It's a VPN problem. The process start has been executed since it tries to establish a connection. Closing it. (Maybe ask on superuser)

Comment: @Sascha even though the vpn works fine outside of this c# code you wouldn't consider there is a programming solution to my problem?
I connect to it everyday manually and have never received he error 800.

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? I would start there. Pretty muchs sounds like auth or network error. Though it is somehow strange it works by manually connecting. Maybe a different user account?